# Calling patial view inside a patial view in a tab content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I do have a Tab content , there I have loaded two patial views
I need to load another patial view in the same content upon some funcationilites done by the user.

example : Two tabs A and B
 when user click A tab, there will be several links listed down. ( link 1, link 2...)
 when user click one that link data should be loaded ( this is another patial view ) under the tab A

appreciate if anyone can help on this

Comment: Use ajax to load that partial view on click event.

Comment: used @Ajax.ActionLink to bind the link but it didnt work

Comment: You should share the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using ajax requests. After loading the tabs write the ajax requests in the tab.

According to your Example, In the partial view loaded in the A tab write the ajax request in the click event of the links.